# How to check whether a certain value is entered in a textfield in Java

Tags: java, swing, boolean

Does anyone know how to check whether someone entered something in a textfield in java which isn't allowed (depending on my requirements)?

It is my intention that no special characters can be entered, but now it's possible to enter "=true" (according to the function, it then satisfies, because it returns a true). I've written a function to check whether the username is correct or not.

Comment: Having your current code improves repeatability

Comment: *"boolean in a textfield"* (shudder) Use a `JCheckBox` for this! It's the right tool for the job.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I think, you're don't understand my problem. I've editted my question. It should only be possible that the name consists only of letters and numbers. But now it's possible to gain access when you put "=true" in jTextfield.

Comment: Without your code, this is impossible to answer

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved it. I made a string variable that retrieves the entered text and add a trim() and toLowerCase() function. Then I check if the entered value is equal to certain values and if it contains some special chars. For me it's works well now.